# How do you link the correct ABI versions with GCJ for foregin jars?

Tags: java, minecraft, gcj

I had decided to try and compile minecraft into a native binary.

For that I used the following (approximately, optimization may have differed):

```
gcj -c -O2 -fjni -findirect-dispatch ./minecraft.jar &
gcj -c -O2 -fjni -findirect-dispatch ./jinput.jar & 
gcj -c -fjni -findirect-dispatch ./lwjgl.jar &
gcj -c -fjni -findirect-dispatch ./lwjgl_util.jar &
```

Then I tried linking:

```
gcj -o mc_out -findirect-dispatch -fjni -L/natives/*64.so \
    -L/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.4/jre/lib/amd64/server \
    ./*.o -ljvm \
     --main=net.minecraft.client.Minecraft
```

But if I run the binary, I get this:

```
ryan@ryan ~/.minecraft/bin_native_test $ ./mc_out
libgcj failure: gcj linkage error.
Incorrect library ABI version detected.  Aborting.

Aborted
```

Now, I use instead:

```
gcj -o mc_out -findirect-dispatch -fjni -L/natives/*64.so ./*.o \
    --main=net.minecraft.client.Minecraft
```

I get:

```
ryan@ryan ~/.minecraft/bin_native_test $ ./mc_out
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
   at java.lang.Class.initializeClass(libgcj_bc.so.1)
   at org.lwjgl.LWJGLUtil.getPlatform(mc_out)
   at org.lwjgl.Sys.createImplementation(mc_out)
   at org.lwjgl.Sys.<clinit>(mc_out)
   at java.lang.Class.initializeClass(libgcj_bc.so.1)
   at org.lwjgl.Sys.getTime(mc_out)
   at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.F(mc_out)
   at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.main(mc_out)
Caused by: java.nio.InvalidMarkException
   at java.nio.Buffer.reset(libgcj_bc.so.1)
   at java.nio.DirectByteBufferImpl.duplicate(libgcj_bc.so.1)
   at java.nio.DirectByteBufferImpl.asReadOnlyBuffer(libgcj_bc.so.1)
   at org.lwjgl.LWJGLUtil.loadIcon(mc_out)
   at org.lwjgl.LWJGLUtil.<clinit>(mc_out)
   at java.lang.Class.initializeClass(libgcj_bc.so.1)
   ...7 more
```

How does one suggest solving this?

Comment: Am not sure whether this is your answer but it seems that what you have asked is reported here as bug.http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=624776

Comment: Also i would like to suggest some thing you could compile through GCJ but as you have difficulty in using why don't you use native bundlers like Launch4j and JarBundler. They wrap your jar file and use a real JRE to execute it.

Answer (score -3):

So it seems to me that you would like to decompile Minecraft, presumably for modding. If so then take a look at the Minecraft Coder Pack. It is a series of programs that really make decompiling, recompiling and reobsufcation very easy.

You can take a look at the program [here](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Minecraft_Coder_Pack).

However if you aren't decompiling for modding reasons then just ignore this :)

Comment: No, that is not at all what he wants to do.